# Reverse action of one hot vector in different features in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I had a dataframe with 2 categorical features like this:

[image]

Then use get_dummies to one hot vector these columns:

[image]

**Now I want to get back from one hot vector to first columns, actually a reverse action of get_dummies.
Is there any way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot with filter `1` in [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), then splitting `varible` column and reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df1.astype(str))
```

---

```
df = df.melt(ignore_index=False).query('value == 1')
df[['a','b']] = df['variable'].str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.set_index('a', append=True)['b'].unstack().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with filter in [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html), convert `multiIndex` to `DataFrame` by [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html), splitting and pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.stack().loc[lambda x: x.eq(1)].index.to_frame()
df[['a','b']] = df[1].str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.pivot(0,'a','b').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html) (pandas 1.5+):

```
df_original = pd.from_dummies(df_dummies, sep='_')
```

Output:

```
  EstateTypes AdverTypes
0           1          1
1           1          2
2           1          2
3           1          3
4           1          2
```